# Countable intersection of sets of full measure contains dense indexing set.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $\{A_t\}_{t\in [0,1]}$ with $A_t\subset [0,1]$ be a family of sets, each of full Lebesgue measure. Is it true that we can always find a countable set $I$ dense in $[0,1]$ and such that
$$I\subset \bigcap_{t\in I} A_t \quad ?$$

Comment: No, too many $t$. Think of $A_t = [0,1] \setminus \{t\}$.

Comment: Thank you... silly me!